# How to run bash function in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker

I have a bash function `nvm` defined in `/root/.profile`. `docker build` failed to find that function when I call it in `RUN` step.

```
RUN apt-get install -y curl build-essential libssl-dev && \
    curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.16.1/install.sh | sh
RUN nvm install 0.12 && \
    nvm alias default 0.12 && \
    nvm use 0.12
```

The error is

```
Step 5 : RUN nvm install 0.12
 ---> Running in b639c2bf60c0
/bin/sh: nvm: command not found
```

I managed to call `nvm` by wrapping it with `bash -ic`, which will load `/root/.profile`.

```
RUN bash -ic "nvm install 0.12" && \
    bash -ic "nvm alias default 0.12" && \
    bash -ic "nvm use 0.12"
```

The above method works fine, but it has a warning

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

And I want to know is there a easier and cleaner way to call the bash function directly as it's normal binary without the `bash -ic` wrapping? Maybe something like

```
RUN load_functions && \
    nvm install 0.12 && \
    nvm alias default 0.12 && \
    nvm use 0.12
```

Comment: `RUN bash -c 'nvm install 0.12 && nvm alias default 0.12 && nvm use 0.12'` should do the trick. Does it work for you? (I'm not 100% sure because I don't know how your container is looking in detail)

Comment: It works fine. But I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Ok, check my answer. A shell script is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: You've not accepted my answer so far. What do you mean with a *better* solution?

Comment: [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is not designed for Docker. Do you really want two Node.js in a single container?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Docker's `RUN` doesn't start the command in a shell. That's why shell functions and shell syntax (like `cmd1` && `cmd2`) cannot being used out of the box. You need to call the shell explicitly:

```
RUN bash -c 'nvm install 0.12 && nvm alias default 0.12 && nvm use 0.12'
```

If you are afraid of that long command line, put those commands into a shell script and call the script with `RUN`:

*script.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

nvm install 0.12 && \
nvm alias default 0.12 && \
nvm use 0.12
```

and make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

In Dockerfile put:

```
RUN /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: I need run nvm in some different steps. And I think the right quote of `bash -c` is hard to control when commands are formatted as multiple lines.

Comment: That's why I've suggested to use a shell script.

Comment: I don't get why you need multiple scripts. Can you elaborate on that? Once I got it I may suggest something.

Comment: This is not what I got from [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/run): "`RUN <command>` (*shell* form, the command is run in a shell, which by default is `/bin/sh -c` on Linux or `cmd /S /C` on Windows)".

Comment: yeah I am not sure this answer is right...I was under the impression that each `RUN` command executed its contents in a subshell.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Thanks for letting me know! (overlooked the previous comment) Yeah, this answer is wrong. Will try to reproduce the problem and fix the answer ...

Comment: your answer actually might be right, given what I've read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635472/using-the-run-instruction-in-a-dockerfile-with-source-does-not-work

Comment: :) It is at least not wrong, but normally a single `RUN` command should be enough. Let me try to reproduce it. Probably just my phrasing was wrong or not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

In the very specific case of nvm, I use the following:

```
ADD --link  https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.git#${NVM_VERSION} $NVM_DIR

RUN /bin/bash -c "\
    source ${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install -b --no-progress $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default \
    "
```

The first command (`ADD --link ...`) will install NVM from GitHub into the container (you need to either define the `ARG`s `NVM_DIR` and `NODE_VERSION` or just replace the placeholders in the snippet).
`ADD` will avoid having to install Git into the container itself.

The second command will instantiate a Bash shell and import & use the function definitions from nvm.sh.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).