# Not able to run source command from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is the script in Dockerfile. When I directly get into the docker and run the commands manually it is working fine but why not from the Dockerfile.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y curl git sudo

RUN curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
RUN /bin/sh install_nvm.sh
RUN source ~/.profile
```

**Error:**

> mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

I have tried few of the solutions found like running it as
`RUN /bin/sh -c "source ~/.profile"` and few more but not solving the issue.

Comment: What is inside of the `~/.profile`?

Comment: it has just a command to set env. https://pastebin.com/RpQg58r4 @JackGore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the RUN instruction in a Dockerfile with 'source' does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635472/using-the-run-instruction-in-a-dockerfile-with-source-does-not-work)

Comment: You should probably just use a [standard node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) of the version you need rather than trying to install nvm.  Even if you could `RUN . $HOME/.profile` note that it would be a no-op, because that shell environment wouldn’t carry over to future steps.

Comment: The solutions in there have not worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to this question: [How to solve 'ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device' in Vagrant?](https://superuser.com/q/1160025/385940)

In `~/.profile` there is a line:

```sh
mesg n || true
```

That is incompatible. In order to fix it, make it conditional upon if tty is available ([credit Gogowitsch](https://superuser.com/questions/1160025/how-to-solve-ttyname-failed-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-in-vagrant#comment2135857_1160074)):

```
RUN sed -i ~/.profile -e 's/mesg n || true/tty -s \&\& mesg n/g'
```

This sed command replaces `mesg n || true` (try it, and ignore if it fails) with `tty -s && mesg n`, (only try it if it will succeed) which makes the error message go away

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your command with below command.
`RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.profile"`

Comment: same whether /bin/sh or /bin/bash