# Successful built docker image does not run when environment was built from anaconda

Tags: docker, anaconda, dockerfile

I built a docker image using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ENTRYPOINT [ “/bin/bash”, “-c” ]

ADD angular_restplus.yaml angular_restplus.yaml

RUN ["conda", "env", "create", "-f", "angular_restplus.yaml"]

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate work"]

COPY json_to_db.py json_to_db.py

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:3000", "json_to_db:app"]
```

and command to build it:

```
sudo docker build -t testimage:latest .
```

That runs through:

```
Step 5/7 : RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate work"]
 ---> Running in 45c6492b1c67
Removing intermediate container 45c6492b1c67
 ---> 5b5604dc281d
Step 6/7 : COPY json_to_db.py json_to_db.py
 ---> e5d05858bed1
Step 7/7 : CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:3000", "json_to_db:app"]
 ---> Running in 3ada6fd24d09
Removing intermediate container 3ada6fd24d09
 ---> 6ed934acb671
Successfully built 6ed934acb671
Successfully tagged testimage:latest
```

However, when I now try to use it, it does not work; I tried:

```
sudo docker run --name testimage -d -p 8000:3000 --rm testimage:latest
```

which seems to work fine as it prints

```
b963bdf97b01541ec93e1eb7
```

However, I cannot access the service in my browser and using

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

only shows the intermediate containers needed to create the image from above.

When I try to run it without the `-d` flag, I get

```
gunicorn: 1: [: “/bin/bash”,: unexpected operator
```

Does that mean that I have to change the `ENTRYPOINT` again? If so, to what?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188182/discussion-on-question-by-cleb-successful-built-docker-image-does-not-run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be found in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39777387/1534017). I had to use the

```
"/bin/bash", "-c"
```

part throughout. The following works fine now (using also @larsks' input who deleted his answer meanwhile):

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

COPY angular_restplus.yaml angular_restplus.yaml
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"] 
RUN ["conda", "env", "create", "-f", "angular_restplus.yaml"]
COPY json_to_db.py json_to_db.py
CMD source activate work; gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:3000 json_to_db:app
```

Then one can run

```
docker build -t testimage:latest .
```

and finally

```
docker run --name testimage -d -p 3000:3000 --rm testimage:latest
```

If one now uses

```
docker ps -a
```

one will get the expected outcome:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
61df8ac0432c        testimage:latest    "/usr/bin/tini -- /b…"   16 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   testimage
```

and can then access the service at

```
http://localhost:3000/
```