# Docker permissions between build and run differ

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I just started playing around with Docker yesterday and am having issues between the build environment and the run environment. Build wise I have issues like...

```
RUN install.sh
/bin/sh: 1: install.sh: Permission denied
the command '/bin/sh -c install.sh' returned a non-zero code: 126
```

or ...

```
RUN . sourceme.env
/bin/sh: 1: .: sourceme.env: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c . sourceme.env' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I build using 'sudo docker build -t joes' and
I run using 'sudo docker run  -it joes'

The frustrating thing is that after build failure I can run it, see that I am in the working directory I expected, and run the command that failed during building successfully. So why the discrepancy?

This is on a linux system and I'm using 'FROM ubuntu:18.04'

To bypass the RUN install.sh error I used

```
RUN /bin/sh install.sh
```

which converts to

```
/bin/sh -c /bin/sh install.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Post your entire Dockerfile. The problem is you haven't pointed to the correct location. When you copy it, copy it in and then supply it with the absolute path. 
e.g.

```
COPY install.sh /install.sh
CMD ./install.sh
```

EDIT: if your containers main job is to run the install.sh script then use it with CMD and not RUN. Use run to build env and evth else.

Comment: For this section it's literally just WORKDIR /some/dir => RUN svn co someurl => RUN . sourceme.env   It fails, I then run the container(that was created up to that point by removing the broken line), I see that I am already in /some/dir and I can see the sourceme.env file.

Comment: Actually using /some/dir/sourceme.env works, but the paths inside break. What's the point of WORKDIR if the directory isn't used/visible? Also, my big problem is that /bin/sh and source do not mix. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702425/source-command-not-found-in-sh-shell/13702876 So how do I 'RUN' a command the way I would from a command line without invoking '/bin/sh'

Comment: @JoeManiaci Can you please edit your question and include your Dockerfile? That would help us reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Using the RUN instruction in a Dockerfile with 'source' does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635472/using-the-run-instruction-in-a-dockerfile-with-source-does-not-work) Seems to be the bulk of my issue

That along with running multiple RUN commands instead of RUN ... && ... && ... etc